# Viewing variables in Rstudo

Tags: r

In previous version the View() function in Rstudio automatically displays the value in columnbind format.
I installed a latest version which shows the View(variable) in the form of -

```
   Name             Type              Value
   Variablename    double            value1,value2,value3..
```

I want to change the format of View() function back to the previous way such that View(variable) shows -

```
    V1
1  Value1
2  Value2
3  Value3
4  Value4
5  Value5
.........
```

I had to use View(cbind(variable)) everytime i want to view the values of the variable. Any suggesstions as to how to change this setting in Rstudio?

Comment: Could you share the content of your variable `V1` by using dput(V1)?

Comment: Try running `print()`.